# WooCommerce Rest API create Webhooks

Tags: node.js, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I am trying to use Node.js to create a simple WooCommerce webhook via WooCommerce's Rest API and the node.js library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api).

Here is the node.js script that I have written:

```
const WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: '<url of my hosted site>',
  consumerKey: '<key>',
  consumerSecret: '<secret>',
  version: 'v3'
});

var tempData = {
  name: 'Order updated',
  topic: 'order.updated',
  status: 'Active',
  secret: '<secret>',
  delivery_url: 'https://webhook.site/1c229375-1fba-4d05-a91503d43ec1e23d',
  api_version: 3
};

WooCommerce.post('webhooks', tempData, function(err, data, res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

When I execute this script via the console, I receive the following error:

`{"errors":{"code":"woocommerce_api_disabled","message":"The WooCommerce API is disabled on this site"}}`

If I create a webhook via the wordpress admin panel under the WooCommerce settings area and then try to the node.js api to get a list of the webhooks, it returns the data as normal. But I cannot for some reason create the webhook via the API.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix:
The issue was in the way the `tempData` object was constructed. Here is how the object should be defined:

```
var tempData = {
  webhook: {
    name: 'some name',
    topic: 'order.updated',
    delivery_url: 'some url'
  }
};
```

And that's it. So the issue was not putting the data inside a "webhook" container inside the object.